# Copy and update record expression doesn't work

Tags: f#, linqpad

I'm trying to copy an entity in a table using LinqPad.

```
let dc = new TypedDataContext()
let title = "Some title"

let newestUser= dc.UserIDs |> Seq.filter (fun(x)->x.Funktion="SomeFunction") |> Seq.last

let newUser=  {newestUserwith Title= title}
```

The type '**UserID**' does not contain a field '**Title**'

But Title is a public field. I'm seeing it in the list by using GetFields()

Has anyone any idea what the reason of that is?

Comment: Try to annotate types on symbols you create. What type is `newestUset`? Can you show the definition of that type? `Title` is a field of which type?

Comment: hi @BartekKobyłecki Title is a string and the definition of the entity comes from DataContext (I use LinqPad and UserIDs is a Table)

Comment: `with` works. If you get a compilation error, you are using the wrong type, or your table just doesn't have that database field. Post a minimal, *complete* and *reproducible* example. What you posted isn't complete (the types are missing) nor reproducible

Comment: Are you sure it is a record type?  I get the impression it's a normal class.

Comment: hi @Foole, yes, it is a normal class.

Comment: hi @PanagiotisKanavos, unfortunately it is a LinqPad script. I cannot give the types

Comment: @user278618 then you can't get any answers. LinqPad doesn't prevent you from finding out what the types are. Don't you know what `TypedDataContext` is? What the table's fields are? The table's schema? If `TypedDataContext` is generated from a db table, the error says there's no field named `Title` in the *table*. The name may be `title` for example

Comment: @user278618 what is the *actual* error message? The answer posted by TheQuickBrownFox makes sense, although the error message is *slightly different* than the one you posted

Answer (score 7):

The `with` keyword is used to copy and update [F# records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/records). A record is a dumb set of fields containing values and no internal state, which is easy to copy. It cannot work on normal objects since there is no defined way to copy any given object.

The error message given by F# when trying to use this syntax on a normal object is `The record label 'Title' is not defined`. It would be more helpful if it was `'newestUser' is not a record`.